# Writing to multiple VA locations with a single write operation

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I'm writing an interface with a black-box library (call it "A"), and need to pass it a `void*` allocation.  I want to back this allocation with two separate allocations from two other libraries (call them "X" and "Y"), duplicating all writes to both allocations.  In essence, I want to "fork" all writes to two existing VA ranges.  The trick is that these allocations can be very large, but only have a few bytes written sparsely, so copying the whole allocation isn't an option.  Currently, I'm using [write-watch memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a third allocation I create myself to accomplish this, but is there a more efficient way to do this?  Alternatively, is there a way to *add* the write-watch property to an existing allocation created by library X or Y?

Basically, this is what I'm doing today (semi-pseudocode):

```
void* x = LibraryX.Allocate(size);
void* y = LibraryY.Allocate(size);

void* a = VirtualAlloc(size, WRITE_WATCH);

LibraryA.WriteSomeStuffToRandomLocations(a);

addresses = GetWriteWatch(a);
for(auto p : addresses)
{
    memcpy(x, p, size);
    memcpy(y, p, size);
}
```

Ideally, I could have something like this though:

```
void* x = LibraryX.Allocate(size);
void* y = LibraryY.Allocate(size);

void* a = GetVARangeThatDuplicatesAllWritesTo(x, y);

LibraryA.WriteABunchOfStuff(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If those external libraries are allocating memory, there's nothing you can do. If you controlled the allocation and format you could use VirtualProtect to have both addresses point to the same physical memory location. This would be especially attractive if the data is sparse, because you could only commit pages as needed.

So the short answer is "not with that design."

I advise you to carefully check the cost of WriteWatch, and how often it's triggered. You may be surprised by the expense and the number of memcpy() calls you end up making.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you can control the physical allocation yourself, make two virtual addresses refer to the same physical page. However, there is no way to take two physical pages and make them the same, and since your LibraryY and LibraryX presumably allocates normal virtual memory that has it's own unique physical pages for each allocation (in other words, the memory allocation is done with something like `HeapAlloc`, `malloc`, `realloc`, C++'s `new` and other such functions).